# I can't use my ubuntu software center?

Tags: 11.10

I am using ubuntu 11.10 version .. when I try to open the ubuntu software center it opens but gives me a blank screen and nothing shows up , before this happens it used to open normally but I couldn't install or upgrade anything from it as an error used to pop up that I have to remove something and it also refused to remove it ! so please I need a solution for this .

Comment: open up a terminal and launch `software-center` from there. Hopefully, you will see some error output. Either that will already help you solving your problem or you can paste it here.

Comment: I launched it and the same thing happened again , a blank screen and nothing more

Comment: no there it actually opens and fails to install but mine doesn't open in the first place .

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling it. Try this instead:

1. Open Terminal
2. type `sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center`

Do not try opening it from terminal. You're just doing more work.

I had this problem many times and I tried doing so many things and none of them worked.